# Decoupling payment classes

Tags: php, finance, laravel

I have several classes for payment handling, I separate these classes into directories like below. Actually I'm going to use it for Laravel project but to make it simple, maybe we can talk as if it's native PHP code.

```
\Payment
    PaymentServiceAdapterInterface.php -> an interface for service adapter 
    PaymentServiceBase.php -> an abstract class for doing common things
    PaymentService.php -> the class that interacts to external code that is doing Payment things

    \Paypal
        Paypal.php -> paypal wrapper class for calling API's
        PaypalService.php -> the class to provide paypal services
        PaypalServiceAdapter.php -> the class that provide uniform methods to be called by PaymentService.php

    \Stripe
        Stripe.php 
        StripeService.php 
        StripeServiceAdapter.php
```

`PaymentService` class:

```
class PaymentService {

    public function __construct(PaymentServiceAdapterInterface $gateway)
    {
         $this->gateway = $gateway;
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
         $this->gateway->authorize();
    }

    public function capture()
    {
         $this->gateway->capture();
    }
}
```

`PaypalServiceAdapter` class is like the following (for Stripe would be similar) - for simplicity let's say we have only 2 methods (authorize and capture), please don't care too much about codes inside the method, it's just an example that each gateway may have different implementation.

```
class PaypalServiceAdapter extends PaymentServiceBase implements PaymentServiceAdapterInterface {

    public function __construct(PaypalService $paypal)
    {
        $this->paypal = $paypal;
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        $this->paypal->prepare();
        $this->paypal->authorize(); 
    }

    public function capture()
    {
        $this->paypal->capture(); 
    }
}
```

To make it short, I don't provide the code of PaypalService.php and Paypal.php, it's pretty obvious I think (but let me know if it's not).

My questions:

1. Am I doing it right? Please forgive me if there is any wrong term (and maybe the name of classes) and please let me know how/what it should be.
2. If I want to make each gateway as separate package, which means it won't use external class or interface like `PaymentServiceBase` and `PaymentPaymentServiceAdapterInterface`, where do I put `PaymentServiceAdapterInterface`? Do I need to duplicate it on each package (and keep one in `Payment` directory as it's needed by `PaymentService` class constructor)?